# Развернуть двусвязный список си

Tags: c, двусвязный-список

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int field;
    struct Node* prev;
    struct Node* next;
} tNode;



void AddElemEnd(tNode** head, int NewField) {
    tNode* Elem;
    Elem = malloc(sizeof(tNode)); // Выделяем память под узел , создаем узел
    assert(Elem);// Проверяем выделение памяти
    Elem->field = NewField; // Присваивание значения узлу
    Elem->next = NULL; // Следующий - ноль
    if (!*head) {
        Elem->prev = NULL;
        *head = Elem;
    }
    else {
        tNode* last = *head;
        while (last->next != NULL)
            last = last->next; // Сдвигаем голову списка
        Elem->prev = last;
        last->next = Elem;
    }
}

void Reverse(tNode **head) {
    tNode *curr=*head; //Текущий - голова списка
    //tNode *Elem = NULL; // Предыдущий становиться текущим присваиваем значение Elem?
    tNode *Elem = curr->prev;
    tNode *Neib = curr->next;
    while (curr != NULL) { // Пока не дойдем до конца списка
    //    tNode *Elem = curr->prev;
    //  tNode *Neib = curr->next;
        //Elem = curr->prev;
        curr->prev = curr->next; // Меняем ссылки местами (следующий становиться предыдущим)
        curr->next = Elem; // Устанавливаем ссылку на следующий
        curr = Neib;
        curr = curr->prev; // Сдвигаем дальше по списку
    }
    if (Elem != NULL) 
        curr = Elem->prev;
}

void FreeMemory(tNode *head) {
    while (head) {
        tNode *next = head->next;
        free(head);
        head = next;
    }
}

void PrintFunc(tNode *head) {
    tNode *p = head;
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%d", p->field);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    tNode *head = NULL;
    int c, d, val, in, ne;
    printf("Number of elements\n");
    scanf("%d", &d);
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        printf("Input %dth element", i);
        scanf("%d", &val);
        AddElemEnd(&head, i);
    }
    Reverse(&head);
    PrintFunc(head);
    FreeMemory(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста.
Как развернуть двусвязный список?

Comment: Вы можете для этого использовать рекурсию, стек или просто цикл. Примеров в интернете вагон.

Comment: Это - да))), примеров "вагон". Но с реализацией у меня ничего не получается. Хотя-бы через цикл. Написал я на форум от безысходности)))

Comment: Ну самое простое, но не самое эффективное - закиньте элементы в стек, вытащите в обратном порядке и проставьте нужные ссылки, вот и все.

Comment: Изымаете голову списка, пока он не станет пустым и включаете ее в начало другого списка (изначально пустого). Потом присваиваете указателю на первый список указатель на второй. Все.

Comment: Ни @avp, ни кто-либо другой не предложили эффективного метода. На самом деле двусвязный список не требует разворотов — это бессмысленная трата ресурсов. Просто обходите его когда надо в обратном порядке.